# Implementing Yeti Built Foundation 6 Theme in to Big Commerce Stencil

Tags: zurb-foundation, bigcommerce, yeti-launch

How would I go about implementing my Foundation 6 based site in to the Big Commerce stencil framework as a store theme?

My site was built in Zurbs Yeti development process.

What would be the best practices and ways to do so?

Kind Regards,
Shane

Comment: https://developer.bigcommerce.com/themes/

Comment: I'm using the stencils framework not the old Blueprint Theme.

Answer (score 0):

We have some information listed [here](https://stencil.bigcommerce.com/docs/componentsdesign-patterns) about the files installed by the ZURB Foundation framework.

Stencil's Foundation support is limited to version 5.5.3, so you may have difficulty trying to use a higher version, but I'd reference the link above for more info on achieving this.